# If - then - do/else in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a question regarding if-then-else/do statements in R.  Based on the internet, my R manuals, and this website, I see that R works differently in this arena than other programming languages because of vectors, but I'm not quite sure I understand and thus am unable to get the following function to work.

I am trying to have R do a calculation based on whether the variable, `pc`, is 0 or 1.  If `pc = 0`, then it should create an average customized for `pc = 0` or `pc = 1`.  The output should be `avecount`.  Here's my code:

```
avecount <- if (pc == 0) {
    sum(sumcount/23)
} else if (pc == 1) {
    sum(sumcount/12)
} else {
    FALSE
}
```

There are other ways to do this exact same function such as subsetting each by `pc` and then merging them together in a dataset, but my gut feeling is that this is not the most efficient way to accomplish this.  Please help!

```
Data:
pc  sumcount    avecount
0   15  
0   24
1   1
1   19
0   1
```

Comment: can you provide input data and expected output ?

Comment: Your code will work if `pc` is a single number but will not give you what you want if it's a vector. If you edit with what your input and output data look like, we can point you in the right direction. One option is `ifelse`, which unlike `if` is vectorized.

Comment: Nested `ifelse` calls could do what you want

Comment: Don't use `if` when you intend to loop over rows. It's not the same function as the SAS/SPSS `IF`. See the examples in SO  showing how to use ifelse and Boolean expressions such as `avecount <- (pc == 0)*sum( sumcount / 23) + (pc == 1) * sum(sumcount / 12)`  . The FALSE would be coerced to 0 which is what would be returned in the case of pc not being 0 or 1. All this would go out the window if you are using `attach` for any of this.

Comment: The function you want is `ifelse`. See the linked question for examples.